# Prevent videos played with JW Player on website from being downloaded

Tags: download, blocking, rtmp, wowza

I'm using RTMP streaming using the WOWZA media streaming server for playing my video files on my website on JW player. I want to **block** downloading of the videos using software like Internet download manger(IDM). Could someone please help me out regarding this issue.??..

Answer (score 3):

What you want is impossible. Seen from the server, there is no difference between a client, that connects to a stream and then displays it and a client, that connects to a stream and the saves it to disk.

You can go the route of only allowing a special client under your control with some sort of cryptographic verification, turning this into a DRM system. Please understand, that the first rule of DRM is: "DRM does not work".

Long story short: If you can watch it, you can record it.

Comment: Don't necessarily need "DRM", just need a client player that uses an encoding/protocol nobody else cares about .. but someone could always handycam (*shudder*).

Comment: Which is one implementation of DRM, albeit a bad one: Security through obscurity

Answer (score 2):

let me join Eugen Rieck in saying that it's impossible. What you can achieve is making it impossible to download and steal for most of the people though. There is a fair article on this [wowza security topic](http://wowzatoolbox.com/wowza-security-and-stream-protection) which I suggest you reading. Thinking in extremes: actually instead of downloading they can just record the video with their cheap HD-capable mobile phone and that's it. Generally: **if they can watch it, they can capture it** with this or that software or trick.

Let me suggest you something that you can do though: [authenticate your stream players](http://wowzatoolbox.com/user-authentication), so that they need to visit your site or better log in to your site so that they can't access your videos from elsewhere. This at least keeps traffic on your site.

Hope it helps

Comment: I know that its impossible to prevent capturing the video. Matter of fact as far as we are using the streaming server to play the videos its impossible to download with the normal plugins and software, and here im doing in that way only. But IDM is downloading bit-by-bit as we are streaming using the streaming server. I got an idea , its like blocking the plugins in the particular site, but im not sure whether it will work or not. Just let me know your views  on this.

Comment: There are many videos on youtube how to use tools like rtmpdump to grab streams. You might be able to block IDM, but there are hundreds of tools to do this. I doubt that IDM is the most popular, I have never used it, only some others.